# How to disable ssh strict host checking on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line

My PC is Windows 10 Pro, 22H2

In my closed work environment, I SSH from Windows command line into many devices that all have the same IP (one at a time, not concurrently on my network at the same time).  I'm running an automated test script and I constantly have trouble scripting something when this warning gets thrown up during the login to a new device that I'm testing.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:{hash}
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:3
ECDSA host key for 192.168.1.5 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I'm using password-based login to these devices.

I made C:\Users\myusername\config with contents:

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

But this didn't stop the warning from happening and blocking the attempt.  So far the only solution I have is to constantly delete the C:\Users\myusername\known_hosts file.  Is there any way to get Windows to ignore strict checking?

Answer (score 4):

Setting StrictHostKeyChecking no also doesn't work for me.  I am using this instead:

Set your config file at `%UserProfile%\.ssh\config` to

```
Host *
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

This will always delete the known_hosts file so the warning will never happen.

Comment: This didn't solve it for me. There was no config file in that directory and when I added it, it had no effect. Update: adding `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to my ssh command solved it.

Answer (score 1):

in windows 10, the path for the file is: `%UserProfile%\.ssh\config`